# Reading csv file with Unicode charcters throws exception

Tags: c#-4.0, csv, odbc, sqldatasource, dataview

Csv file might have multilingual characters.

Below is my code to read it in `DataView`

```
List<BulkUser> _lstBulkUser = new List<BulkUser>();
            DataView BlukUserView;

            try
            {
                using (SqlDataSource _SqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource())
                {
                    //_SqlDataSource.ConnectionString = "Dsn=outlook;dbq=D:\\selvam\\projectlist\\lates\\trunk\\SLVconsoleApp\\SLVconsoleApp.Web\\Uploads\\CSVFiles;defaultdir=D:\\selvam\\projectlist\\lates\\trunk\\SLVconsoleApp\\SLVconsoleApp.Web\\Uploads\\CSVFiles;driverid=27;fil=text;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5";
                    _SqlDataSource.ConnectionString = "Dsn=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutlookDns"].ToString() + ";dbq=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutlookFileFolder"].ToString() + ";defaultdir=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutlookFileFolder"].ToString() + ";driverid=27;fil=text;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5";
                    _SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT [First Name] As First_Name, [Last Name] AS LAST_NAME, Company, [E-mail Address] AS EMAILID FROM [" + Filename + "]";
                    _SqlDataSource.ProviderName = "System.Data.Odbc";
                    BlukUserView = (DataView)_SqlDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
                    int i = 1;
                    _lstBulkUser = (from value in BlukUserView.Table.Select() select new BulkUser { ID = Convert.ToString(i++), FirstName = Convert.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])value["First_Name"])), LastName = value["LAST_NAME"].ToString(), EmailId = value["EMAILID"].ToString(), Company = value["Company"].ToString() }).ToList();
                    if (File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutlookFileFolder"].ToString() + "\\" + Filename))
                    {
                        File.Delete(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutlookFileFolder"].ToString() + "\\" + Filename);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
            }
```

it throws U`nable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.`

Even if i tried Unicode characters it is not! how do i overcome this issue ?

Below is the screenshot of the csv file

[image]

Comment: Better post the input conditions triggering this error in order to get help quickly.

Comment: screenshot as enclosed. please have a look.

Comment: I don't know anything about the language displayed on your pic (don't know the language and, logically, neither the encoding). Usually, errors triggered when reading different languages (than the ones accounted by the default encoding system in your program) are provoked by selecting the wrong encoding (you should know which encoding should be applied). In your specific code, I am not sure what is the point of doing a casting to byte (what actually is provoking the error).

Comment: @varocarbas actually it throws that error when encode the Japanese characters in that XL. I need to bind First Name, Last Name, Company and E-Mail Address which may in different languages. so i need a unicode support.this is my actual issue.

Comment: If you have different encodings, you have to account for different encodings (knowing the exact encoding of the given chunk of text is not an easy matter at all); in any case, you should get a bunch of weird symbols rather than an error in case of choosing a wrong encoding. Also this line casting to byte seems wrong (and actually this is what the error says). I am not used to this specific conditions; but if you post a relevant input set I (or anyone else) might do a quick test to help you out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

CSV doesn't support with multilingual characters. i have checked up to Ms-office 2010.

It is better to save as xls or xlsx. the easiest way to handle this situation.